# Could a Cadet heater release metallic dust into the air?

Tags: thermodynamics, metals

A Cadet style wall is periodically making a hissing sound. While it makes this sound, I notice my computer mouse is non-responsive. What is the most likely cause of the hissing sound, and how dangerous is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the thermostat cuts off, two springy metal contacts are supposed to pop out of contact, which is supposed to completely halt the flow of electricity to the heater element.

If those contacts fail to completely separate, then a stream of sparks of electricity will jump across the (small) gap between them. This "arcing" will produce *radiated* and *conducted electromagnetic interference* which will disrupt electronic gear in the vicinity, produce a frying-bacon sound- AND create ozone plus microscopic spherules of melted and burnt contact material which can contain tiny amounts of copper, beryllium, iron, chromium or nickel depending on what alloy the spring contacts are made of.

Burning contacts are DANGEROUS because they can catch the heater on fire in addition to poisoning the air. THROW THE HEATER AWAY!

Comment: A friend says: "I agree that arcing could produce NPs, but not at 220V." Also, my breaker has never tripped and I've never smelled any burning metal or anything else while the sizzling sound is happening? Can you comment on these points?

Comment: arcing can occur at almost any voltage if the gap is small enough. note also that the arc gap has the resistance of the heater element in series with it, which limits current (but not voltage). no smell means the arc current is too small to throw any arc spatter, so you are lucky.

Comment: Can you clarify "throw any spatter". Does that mean toxic nanoparticles are probably not being released from the heater?

Comment: yes that is right.

Comment: Thank you for your help.