# How dangerous is this arcing wall heater in terms of nanoparticles / metal vapors?

Tags: thermodynamics, metals

This question is a follow-on to my [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/616111/289738), but now more focused and with pictures.

As described in the [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/616111/289738), the heater sometimes made a hissing noise (imagine white noise, like smooth version of old-time TV static), which I now understand means it was arcing. There was no smell coming from it during these episodes, and nothing seemed to be burning or otherwise dangerous, aside from the noise. The noise/arcing could be stopped easily by turning the thermostat dial in either direction, which is what was generally done whenever the noise started (the thought was that the sound was simple mechanical problem in the heater and not something dangerous). As stated in the [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/616111/289738), there was also electromagnetic interference during the arcing, which caused the computer mouse not to move until the thermostat dial was turned (which of course goes against the theory that it was a simple mechanical problem).

There are many pictures below showing the steps of opening the thermostat mechanism to see the contacts. At the end there are some pictures of a second heater of the same type without this problem.

The question is: How dangerous was this arcing process for someone frequently working near the heater? The worst fear is that vapors of microscopic spherules of melted/burnt contact material were being release into the air, and that these contained tiny amounts of copper, beryllium, iron, chromium, or nickel, depending on what the contacts are made of (my understanding is that beryllium and copper are the most likely). This can cause various health problems, including beryllium poisoning and (the particular concern in this case) sarcoidosis.

I think it's clear from the pictures that the contacts were being eroded by the arcing, and presumably the eroded material was released as metallic vapors / nanoparticles.

Some of the answers to the [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/616111/289738) said that if there was no burning smell or ozone smell (which there wasn't), it should be okay. But looking at the eroded/scratched contacts, it seems like there is nowhere else for that material to go except to be released in vapors, which first collected at the top of the cartridge leaving a brown soot, and then escaped through the edges of the cartridge and from there went into the heater and were blown out with the heated air.

Does that sound right?

---

This is the heater: [Picture-01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvVlV.jpg)

Here is the label and the date (presumably the date it was installed):[Picture-02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L558r.jpg)

Here is the thermostat in place in the heater: [Picture-03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLlrz.jpg)

Here is the thermostat removed from the heater: [Picture-04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OT7z.jpg)

The thermostat holds a cartridge wrapped in cardboard: [Picture-05](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd2lu.jpg)

Here is the cardboard wrapper: [Picture-06](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK0t8.jpg)

Inside the cardboard is what I'll call the cartridge, which has a plastic top and a metal base: [Picture-07](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcIBS.jpg)

The cartridge appears undamaged from the outside : [Picture-08a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAt5t.jpg), [Picture-08b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIH7F.jpg), [Picture-08c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwXlh.jpg), [Picture-08d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2cru.jpg).

Pulling the cartridge apart, we see the top has an accumulation of brown soot. The bottom holds the thermostat mechanism : [Picture-09a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AFiJ.jpg),  [Picture-09b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvXh9.jpg)

Here is the thermostat mechanism. On the right side we see the top contact (attached from the right) touching the bottom contact, connected to the metal spring on the left : [Picture-10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi0Og.jpg)

Another view showing the contacts touching : [Picture-11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJPbz.jpg)

And another view showing some white dust on the base : [Picture-12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3WZX.jpg)

Here the metal has been bent to examine the contacts : [Picture-13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWVHB.jpg)

The bottom contact appears smooth, but is a multi-colored collection of dots, and you can see a halo of brown soot. The white scratches were added by the effort of bending the contact arms open. (Several pictures here because I had a hard time capturing the details of the color with my camera.): [Picture-14a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjYi5.jpg), [Picture-14b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6pVe.jpg), [Picture-14c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKY0z.jpg), [Picture-14d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ek6Tk.jpg), [Picture-14e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5AyW.jpg)

The top contact appears rough, with an uneven surface (again, the white scratches are probably all from the effort of prying the contact up to view it): [Picture-15a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj2qN.jpg), [Picture-15b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWqTB.jpg), [Picture-15c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfWQA.jpg), [Picture-15d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE5X9.jpg).

Finally, here are some pictures of a second heater that is being replaced, that never made an arcing sound and has clean looking contacts. Note that according to the date (1991) this second heater is actually older than the first (1998). However, the second heater was used very infrequently by the current tenant. Whether previous tenants used it is unknown : [Picture-16a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDzig.jpg),  [Picture-16b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOQiT.jpg).

Here you can see both the top and bottom contacts, which look smooth and clean : [Picture-17a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma0uA.jpg), [Picture-17b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otpkd.jpg), [Picture-17c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raL7W.jpg), [Picture-17d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57uea.jpg), [Picture-17e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mmqd.jpg).

And of course the second heater's cartridge cover is clean : [Picture-18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkiMU.jpg).

---

Finally, here are some pictures of a second heater that is being replaced, that never made an arcing sound and has clean looking contacts. Note that according to the date (1991) this second heater is actually older than the first (1998). However, the second heater was used very infrequently by the current tenant. Whether previous tenants used it is unknown.

[image: Second heater date]
[image: Second heater label]

Here you can see both the top and bottom contacts, which look smooth and clean:
[image: Second heater contacts]
[image: Second heater contacts]
[image: Second heater contacts]
[image: Second heater contacts]
[image: Second heater contacts]

And of course the second heater's cartridge cover is clean:
[image: Second heater cover]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the excellent documentation, here are some more thoughts.

The switch with the burnt contacts was fully enclosed, which means most of the burnt particulates stayed inside the housing and never got out. The fact that you smelled no ozone, etc. while the switch was "sizzling" supports this idea.

This means that your chances of being poisoned by metal particles from the arcing contact points are very low.

If you know someone with an electron microscope it would be fun to see a sample of the brown soot under high magnification. Note also that a chemical analysis of the soot could be run inside the microscope, if it is equipped with the right accessories.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, niels nielsen. I was going to comment on the other question to ask you to look at this one, but you beat me to it. My question is: I imagine those metal particles creating a "vapor," which in my mind I was thinking of as a gas that had more volume than the particles themselves. So I was imaging it being forced out of the cartridge just because of the volume. But what you write makes it sound like there wasn't an increased volume, so the particles just kind of collected at the top of the cartridge, or fell to the bottom, and had nothing forcing them out?

Comment: By the way, do you know what's up with the multi-colored dots of the bottom contact? Is that how the contact looked originally, or was a top layer removed, exposing those colors? And why all the different colors?

Comment: In a previous lifetime I was a materials scientist, and those colors intrigued the hell out of me. Microscopes are needed. powerful microscopes. and etchants too.

Comment: Can you comment on the question of gases? In particular, if ozone is produced, isn't that a gas that would escape from the cartridge and bring some particles with it. In my case I didn't smell ozone, but if it was a relatively small amount that wouldn't create a smell (and my understanding is that the smell of ozone is somewhat subtle), wouldn't that escape? Or does the fact that there's no sign of brown soot except on the top inside of the cartridge mean all the particles are up there and not escaping?

Comment: If you've ever smelled ozone, you'll know it. the nose is sensitive to it at very low levels. Based on your photos, the particulates did not escape.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help.